# Printing photos to a specific size

Tags: lightroom, printing, aspect-ratio

I have a Mac and Lightroom 4 and a full frame camera Nikon D700

Wishing to upload a photo to my lab for a photo to be printed at 10 x 8

Using Lightroom what should the aspect ratio be.

Do I choose from Width & Height, Long Edge,  Dimensions, or Megapixels?

And what image size do I enter to achieve the 10 x 8?

Do I check or uncheck resize to fit size within the export Module of Lightroom?

Answer (score 4):

The export dialog has nothing to do with the aspect ratio of the image. Those options are for scaling the image. Use the develop tab to crop the image to the correct aspect ratio. The option is on the right after the crop mode is activated.

[image]

Once the image is cropped to your liking export at the desired quality and send it to the lab for printing.

Most photo labs will take the wrong aspect ratio and do a center crop or leave white margins if you send the wrong size. Doing it in Lightroom will give you more control.

Comment: @Sue - Just to be clear, in case you did not know. The D7000 produces images of 3:2 aspect ratio, if uncropped you would get something like a 12x8.

Comment: I have a Nikon D700 .  What happens if I want a 10 x 8 and not a 8 x 10 .  (1)What do I do?                        (2)  What information do I type in the Export Module re sizing?

Comment: To rotate the aspect ratio you enter crop mode. Hold shift while re-sizing to constrain ratio. Then drag the top right re-size tab down to the bottom left and then kind of up to the left to make it flip. Or just press "X" while in crop mode to flip orientation (untested by me).